# Migrating chrome extension from manifest v2 to v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, eval, manifest

I need to migrate some chrome extensions to manifest v3. Previously we are using eval() function which is giving error now for V3. Please help me out what should be use instead f eval(). Sample code is given below.

```
var FirstFunction = function (data) {
    // some data coming from DB
    eval(data);
    // issue occurs at this point "Uncaught (in promise) EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'"."
}
```

in data we have below piece of code:

```
var demoEmrCustomInterval = setInterval(function () {
   
    try {
        counter++;
        try {
            var pName = $("#attendantData  .patientInfo .ptName span:first")
                .text()
                .trim();
            var pDOB = document.getElementsByName("pat")[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById("text_DOB")
                .innerText.trim();
        }
        catch (e) { }
        if (((pName == "" || pName == null || pName == "null" || pName == undefined) || (pName == "" || pName == null || pName == "null" || pName == undefined)) && userSettingsShowPatinetWidgentOnChart_Cookie) userSettingsShowPatinetWidgentOnChart = true;
        else userSettingsShowPatinetWidgentOnChart = false;
        setsessionStorage(pName, pDOB, "M");
    }
    catch (e) {
        if (userSettingsShowPatinetWidgentOnChart_Cookie) userSettingsShowPatinetWidgentOnChart = true;
        else userSettingsShowPatinetWidgentOnChart = false;
    }
}, 50);;
window.IsAutomatchTimerCurrentlyRunning = 1;
window.setInterval = function (window, setInterval) {
    if (!window.timers) {
        window.timers = {};
    }
    if (!window.timers.intervals) {
        window.timers.intervals = {};
    }
    if (!window.timers.intervals.active) {
        window.timers.intervals.active = {};
    }
    return function (func, interval) {
        var id = setInterval(func, interval);
        window.timers.intervals.active[id] = func;
        return id;
    }
}(window, window.setInterval);
```

Comment: The code you've shown isn't really enough to understand the problem: what is in `data`? Perhaps you could give a small example of how it might look?

Comment: @IMSoP i edit and provide what is in data